# Python: How to check for the next index in list if exception occurs in present index of python list

Tags: python, exception

I am trying a simple code in python where I have a list of dictionaries and I will be filtering out the value based on the key among the dictionaries.

My list of dictionaries is this:

```
Mylist = [
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600, "type": "MX"},
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600},
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600, "type": "A"},
]
```

I want to extract the dictionary which has the key value pair as "type": "A" To do that, I am using the operation code of:

```
a = list(filter(lambda type: type['type'] == 'A', Mylist))
```

There is no problem with this code. The matter is that, the 2nd dictionary does not have a key called "Type" so it throws a KeyError exception and the programs stops without checking the 3rd dictionary or the 2nd index of the list.

What I want is to ignore the keyerror in the 2nd dictionary and check the 3rd dictionary and print out the dictionary which has key value "type"="A"

So I tried using try/except.

```
Mylist = [

{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600, "type": "MX"},
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600},
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600, "type": "A"},
]

IP_Data =[]
for dicti in Mylist:

    try:
        a = list(filter(lambda type: type['type'] == 'A', Mylist))
        IP_Data.append(a)

    except:
        continue
print(IP_Data)

input()
```

I have made the result of a store in another list called IP_Data. when I run the code, I get the result as an empty array i.e. [] 
Can someone tell me why as to why this happens and any way of making the whole dictionary store inside the array whose key value is type=A

p.s I also tried pass instead of continue but I still get the same issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dict.get()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html) method on the dictionary to avoid the cases where the dictionary doesn't have that particular key, you can set a default value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. Try this :

```
Mylist = [
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600, "type": "MX"},
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600},
{"data": "two.mail-in.daimler.com.", "ttl": 3600, "type": "A"},
]
a = list(filter(lambda type: type.get('type', None) == 'A', Mylist))
```

**Output** :

```
[{'data': 'two.mail-in.daimler.com.', 'ttl': 3600, 'type': 'A'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using key to access the value in the code

```
a = list(filter(lambda type: type['type'] == 'A', Mylist))
```

You can modify your code to use the .get method of a dictionary object.

```
a = list(filter(lambda type: type.get('type','') == 'A', Mylist))
```

Here, if the key 'type' doesn't exists you can pass a default value as the second argument, which in this case I have passed as "" (empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Dont override built in function `type`, instead of explicitly trying to get dictionary key, try using `dictionary.get('key', None)`, and this way you will not get key error.